# Change background of rectangle without inner elements

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have concatenated rectangles like so:

```
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node [rectangle, draw, text width=4em, fill=white] (b) {B};
\node [rectangle, draw, text width=4em, right=of b, fill=white] (a) {A}; 
\node [rectangle, draw, fit=(b) (a), fill=orange, fill opacity=0.1] (local) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result of the above is this:

[image]

My problem is that I do not want inner boxes A & B to have the orange background (i.e. they should not be coloured..). How can I fix this please? (still new to Tikz!)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Does adding `fill=white` to the inner nodes do what you want? `\node [rectangle, draw,text width=4em,fill=white] (b) {B};` and then fill the big node on the background layer.

Comment: Thank you, no it does not work. I think because the last fill is overriding previous ones.. I have updated my code above to reflect this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning,backgrounds}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node [rectangle, draw,text width=4em,fill=white] (b) {B};
\node [rectangle, draw,text width=4em, right=of b,fill=white] (a) {A}; 
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node [rectangle, draw, fit=(b) (a),fill=orange,fill opacity=0.1] (local) {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course. It was just asking me to wait..